# html5 design breaks in IE8 compatibility view mode

Tags: html, internet-explorer, compatibility

We have a website designed using html5 tags. As IE doesn't support HTML5 tags yet, I applied the `document.createElement` fix and it works fine. But 'compatibility view' mode enabled, the design breaks. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Compatibility view is intended for viewing older pages, which newer versions of IE may not render as originally intended. You shouldn't really need to design new pages for compatibility view.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 has very limited support for HTML5 elements. Whether in compatibililty view or without it, it does not add support for otherwise unsupported elements. Similarly using document.createElement does not mean IE* would start supporting HTML5 elements.